# Graphing A Polar Equation

Tags: polar-coordinates

So, I encountered a question r = -|sinø|. So, I thought the polar graph would look like (2) but it actually looks like (3) and I don't understand why. Can someone explain it to me? I've attached a picture. [image]

Comment: Are you sure $r=-|\sin \theta|?$ It is $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\ge 0.$

Comment: @mfl: In polar coordinate, $r$ indicates the coordinate of the given point on the rotated axis (by an angle $\theta$).

Comment: @QuangHoang Thank you for the clarification. So, when the angle is between $180$ and $360$ the positive part of the axis would be under $y=0.$ If I understand correctly this would be the reason.

Comment: @mfl I'm sorry I don't understand the explanation. Shouldn't everything be below the x-axis since 90 and 270 are negative in the cartesian graph?

Comment: On a polar graph, r is "distance from the origin", and pays no concern to whether it's above or below the x-axis. A negative r means "distance from the origin, in the opposite direction to what would be otherwise". So perhaps the easiest way to get the plot working would be to graph $r=|\sin(\theta)|$ and then, for each point, map it to the point directly opposite it going through the origin.

Comment: When you rotate the axis by an angle $\theta\in (0,90)$ the "positive numbers" on the axis are on the first quadrant. If you have an angle $\theta\in (90,180)$ the "positive numbers" on the axis are on the second quadrant. This agrees with your idea of the graph. But if you rotate the axis by an angle $\theta\in (180,270)$ the "positive numbers" are on the third quadrant. For this reason it appears the part of the "circle" on the first quadrant.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** The absolute value of a function is always greater-than-or-equal to zero, and similarly the *negative* of the absolute value will always be less-than-or-equal to zero.

Thus, the polar equation you posted implies that for any angle $0\le\varphi\le 2\pi$, the radial coordinate $r$ is never positive, because:

$$r{(\varphi)}=-|\sin{\varphi}|\le 0.$$

Angular coordinates in the range $0\le\varphi\le\pi$ usually correspond to the top half of the plane when the radius $r$ is positive. So, negative values of $r$ will fall in what part of the plane?

Next, consider the same questions for the case when $\pi\le\varphi\le2\pi$.

Comment: In this link https://cims.nyu.edu/~kiryl/Calculus/Section_9.3--Polar_Coordinates/Polar_Coordinates.pdf the author uses an extension of polar coordinates to allow $r<0.$